# How to extract parameters from string tested with regular expression

Tags: regex, scala

I am developing application, which receive text commands:

For example text command `play film ramboo first blood tv`.

First, I need test command matching. Then, I need extract parameters from it:

```
media = film,
name = ramboo first blood
source = tv
```

For matching check I build regular expression.

Here my command definition:

```
sealed trait WordLike {
  def parameter: String
}
case class Word(parameter: String, variants: Set[String] = Set.empty) extends WordLike
case class Any(parameter: String) extends WordLike


case class CommandDef(sentence: List[WordLike]) {

  private lazy val regexp = {

    def acc(r: String, sentence: List[WordLike]): String = {
      sentence match {
        case x :: xs =>
          x match {
            case Word(p, variants) => acc(r + "(" + variants.mkString("|") + ")", xs)
            case Any(p) => acc(r + ".*", xs)
          }
        case Nil => r
      }
    }
    acc("^", sentence) + "$"
  }

  def `match`(text: String): Boolean = text.matches(regexp)

}
```

Regular expression in example above : `^(play)(film|song).*(tv|pc)$`

I use my code like this:

```
val cmd = CommandDef(List(
  Word("play"),
  Word("media", variants = Set("film", "music")),
  Any("name"),
  Word("source", variants = Set("tv", "pc"))))


cmd.`match`("play film ramboo first blood tv")
```

I have no idea how to extract parameters from text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Capture groups can be used to extract parameters

```
val pattern = """^(play) (film|song) (.*) (tv|pc)$""".r("command", "media", "name", "source")

pattern.findFirstMatchIn("play film ramboo first blood tv").foreach { m =>
  println(s"media = ${m.group("media")}")
  println(s"name = ${m.group("name")}")
  println(s"source = ${m.group("source")}")
```

Output:

```
media = film
name = ramboo first blood
source = tv
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex from the answer by @olik1 is good, but it might be cleaner to use `match` to unpick it:

```
val CommmandPattern = """^(play) (film|song) (.*) (tv|pc)$""".r

def matchCommand(s: String) =
  s match {
    case CommmandPattern(command, media, name, source) =>
      println(s"command=$command, nedia=$media, name=$name, source=$source")
    case _ =>
      println("Failed to parse command")
  }
```

This puts the matched values directly into variables, and allows clean error handling. You can also add multiple patterns to the `match` if you want a more flexible grammar.